# ResultSet compare result object datatype to String

Tags: java

I'm trying to format a decimal before saving it within a hashmap of strings (compared to table names).

Can anyone tell me how I would compare the results set column name datatype with the datatype String.

The closet I can get is:

```
if(metaData.getColumnClassName(i).equals(String.class.getClass()))
```

My Code:

```
while(mResults.next())
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++)
        {
            //ERROR HERE. Try to see if it's string for decimal format on float.

            if(mResults.getObject(metaData.getColumnName(i)).equals(String.class))
            {
                System.out.println("Should be 3.");
            }

            SQLResults.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), mResults.getString(metaData.getColumnName(i)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pleas explain again what you're trying to do? A column name data type makes little sense out of context.

Comment: SQL query returns a results set. I'm trying to compare the datatype from the results set by column but don't know how too. Something is wrong with the IF statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(metaData.getColumnClassName(i).equals("java.lang.Float"))
{
    SQLResults.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), 
        mDF.format(mResults.getFloat(metaData.getColumnName(i))));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ResultSet.getMetadata() method to obtain [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) which provides the column Type (and other information, such as numeric precision).  You can then convert as necessary.  The column type is returned as a [java.sql.Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) int constant, not a Class object.

Comment: Yes and depending on the column type OP should use the relevant method to retrieve the data type. Like getInt, getString etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mResults.getObject(metaData.getColumnName(i)).equals(String.class))
```

How could your object equal `String` class. you can get `Object#getClass#getName` what will return class Name of actaul `Object Type` that can be `String` or `Integer`. Something like -

```
if(mResults.getObject(metaData.getColumnName(i)).getClass().getName.equals("java.lang.String")){}
```

But still it does not make any sence, where it will be useful.

Comment: I'm trying to find the results set datatype.

Comment: You know you database coulmn detail, right? so can map it. why you need to confirm again?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like:

```
if(metaData.getColumnType(i) == Types.VARCHAR)
```

where `metadata` is of type: `ResultSetMetaData`